# Angular changeDetector.detectChanges() breaks matTooltip in *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-8

The matTooltip in following component is redering correctly. The overlay and small bubble for the tooltip is rendered, but the text is missing (although in the html when inspecting in the browser) and it isn't positioned correctly.

Interesting is, that the tooltip works when I remove the detectChanges() call, or it works outside the *ngFor even with detectChanges();

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'mur-app-titlebar',
  templateUrl: './app-titlebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-titlebar.component.scss']
})
export class AppTitlebarComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public appbarItems: IMenuItem[];

  private destroy$ = new Subject();

  constructor(
    private appBarService: AppBarService, // my custom service
    private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef,
  ) {
  }

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.appBarService.getAppbarItems().pipe( //observable comes from outside of angular
      takeUntil(this.destroy$)
    ).subscribe(value => {
      this.appbarItems = value || [];
      // change detection is not triggered automatically when the value is emmited
      this.changeDetector.detectChanges(); 
    });
  }

  public ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next();
  }

}
```

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of appbarItems">
      <button mat-button
              (click)="item.onclick && item.onclick()"
              [disabled]="item.disabled"
              [matTooltip]="item.tooltip"
              [style.color]="item.color">
        <mat-icon *ngIf="item.icon"
                  [class.mr-3]="item.label">
          {{item.icon}}
        </mat-icon>
        <span>{{item.label}}</span>
      </button>
     
    </ng-container>
```

I have verified, that appbarItems is set only once and is not changing

Comment: It seems to be an async operation issue. Move your `ngFor` into the button, use `*ngIf="appbarItems"` and remove the `detectChanges` call. Or assign the pipe into aproperty and use it with the `async` pipe

Comment: Is there a special reason you use the manual subscribe instead of the async pipe?

Comment: Can you please reproduce this issue in stackblitz?

Comment: are you sure you don't encounter any other error in the console? This seems like the rendering stops for some reason. Also ++ for the async pipe suggestions

Comment: Why is change detection not triggered?

Comment: @enno.void: I need to call the detectChanges() manually. Async pipe does not seem to solve the issue with detectChanges().

Comment: @ForestG: No, no error in the console. I've only noticed, that when angular calls DetectChanges (e.g. when I click on the button), the text in the tooltip appears correctly

Comment: @yurzui: Change detection is not triggered automatically, because the Observable pipe comes from external web component. Angular has no way to know, it should trigger change detection, when value is emmited

Comment: What if you would replace detectChanges with `zone.run`?

Comment: @yurzui: setting appBarItems inside zone.run() helped. Could you elaborate on it in your answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you don't need to call `cdRef.detectChanges()` in callback of async operations in Angular.

But if you do it it means that you're trying to solve some problem with view updates. There can be several reasons why component view is not updated after async code:

- your component is hidden for checking under OnPush change detection strategy
- callback is executed outside of Angular zone.

Looks like you faced the second situation. Calling cdRef.detectChanges outside of Angular zone get bring you a situation when some of Angular handlers will be registered outside of Angular zone. As a result view won't be updated as a result of those handlers and you will have call detectChanges in other places or again use zone.run.

Here's an example of such cases https://ng-run.com/edit/XxjFjMXykUqRUC0irjXD?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Your solution might be returning code execution to Angular zone by using `ngZone.run` method:

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}

.subscribe(value => {
  this.ngZone.run(() => this.appbarItems = value || []);
```